# Remote images not following redirect on Android using React Native

Tags: redirect, react-native

There is a longstanding issue in React Native on Android where the `<Image/>` component will not load an image if the uri issues a redirect. Example:

```
<Image source={uri: 'https://example.com/image.jpg'}/>
```

If `https://example.com/image.jpg` responds with a redirect (301, 302 etc) to `https://example.com/redirect.jpg` the `<Image/>` component will not load the image.

Is it possible to load images that follow a redirect?

Answer (score 2):

While the `<Image/>` component does not follow redirects, fetch does and can be used to get the new uri.

```
export const getRedirect = async (uri)=>{
    const response = await fetch(uri)
    const data = await response
    return (data.status === 200 ? data.url : '')
}
```

This can then be used in a new component like this:

```
class RedirectImage extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {uri: ''}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        getRedirect(this.props.uri).then((uri)=>{
            this.setState({uri: uri})
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Image
                {...this.props}
                source={{uri: this.state.uri}}
            />
        )
    }
}

RedirectImage.propTypes = {
    uri: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default RedirectImage
```

Now `<RedirectImage uri={'https://example.com/image.jpg'}/>` will display `https://example.com/redirect.jpg` as desired.

Comment: this solution will make two request  for every none 302 request